# Visual Studio automatically deletes the next word while I type

Tags: visual-studio

This happens every time if I try to enter a class name in front of existing class, it automatically deletes the class name in front

This happens if I add an argument in front of existing arguments in a function, VS just assumes that I'm trying to replace the existing class name, but all I am trying to do is separate the two by a comma.

How can I disable visual studio automatically deleting text in front of cursor

Comment: Are you sure you haven't toggled text insert/text replace mode?  If you hit the `Insert`/`Ins` key, does this stop?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my case, just pressed the insert key in my keyboard and it disappeared.

> Not really a Small Basic question, but it sounds like you have the
> 'insert' key selected.  Check your keyboard for the insert key and
> toggle this just like caps lock.

Source [httpsa://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9c6c26d-acad-42d9-a0ae-107a044f60c1/typing-deletes-leading-letter?forum=smallbasic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9c6c26d-acad-42d9-a0ae-107a044f60c1/typing-deletes-leading-letter?forum=smallbasic)

Answer (score 0):

**Have you installed any auto-save extensions like "Save typing"?** If yes, you should disable it.

Go to the Extensions tab(available on the left panel, or press (Ctrl+Shift+X)). Find the extension using the search bar. Select the extension (eg: "Save Typing" extension) from the list. Click "Disable" button. There may appear a "Reload required" button, press it to reload VSCode for the changes to get reflected.

**Reason:**
Such extensions are meant for coding html,css,etc. which requires auto-saving for live reflection of changes in the webpage. But, these extensions may cause difficulty when you are using other coding languages, especially like GoLang, etc.

Such extensions would try to save our code whenever you type a key. But, GoLang, etc won't allow you to save incomplete code, so, it would revert the change you made in every instance. That is why every word/letter we type is getting deleted.

[Disable "Save Typing" extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NhmF.png)

[Reloading VSCode after disabling extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX1e3.png)

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, could you please tell me which version of Visual Studio you are using? Some extensions installed in your Visual Studio may cause the situation, such as ReSharper.

I suggest you temporarily disable the extensions under Extensions > Manage Extensions > Installed in Visual Studio 2019.

Or, try to use the command: [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to run vs without any extensions, check if the installed extensions affect or not.